# What does this mean in my boss's python code?

Tags: python

This is the code :

```
modulename, classname =  settings.APP_USER_CLASS.rsplit('.',1 )
modulemeta = __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(),  [classname])
```

I don't understand this:  `__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(),  [classname])`  mean ,

so what is it ,

thanks

Comment: Too lazy to Google? http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__

Answer (score 4):

`__import__` is a built-in function that imports a module.  The first argument is the module to load, the fourth is a list of names to import from the module.  So his call is equivalent to:

```
from modulename import classname
```

[Edit]

But I have to agree with Jon's comment to your post.  This is the kind of thing that is not hard to find.